# How to make my query faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, query-optimization

My query here taking more than 30 min. Tell me how to make it faster? What should i do to optimize it to 1 min?

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.BLDGID AS 'CBRE Building Id',
                e.CLIENTCODE AS 'DEXUS Building Id',
                b.BLDGNAME AS 'Building Name',
                cmgr.RMGRNAME AS 'Snr Manager AS',
                cmgr.RMGREMAIL AS 'Snr Manager AS Email',
                cmigr.IMGRNAME AS 'Manager AS',
                cmigr.IMGREMAIL AS 'Manager AS Email',
                ttj.JOBID AS 'TSR No',
                ttj.JobType,
                wws.JobActivity,
                wrj.[Description] AS 'JobActivity Sub-Category',
                ttj.JobDetail AS 'TSR Details',
                wc.contname AS 'Tenant Contact',
                wc.Name AS 'Tenant Company NAME',
                wc.ContName AS 'Tenant Contact',
                wc.Phone AS 'Tenant Phone',
                wc.Mobile AS 'Tenant Mobile',
                wc.Email AS 'Tenant Email',
                TS.Q_Id,
                TA.Answer
FROM BLDG b
JOIN dbo.ENTITY e ON e.ENTITYID = b.ENTITYID
JOIN dbo.CBRERMGR cmgr ON cmgr.RMGRID = e.RMGRID
JOIN dbo.CBREIMGR cmigr ON cmigr.USERID = cmgr.USERID
JOIN WSM_AUNZ..wsm_Ref_Buildings wsmbldg ON wsmbldg.BLDGID = b.BLDGID
JOIN WSM_AUNZ..TSP_TSR_Job ttj ON ttj.BuildingID = wsmbldg.BuildingId
JOIN WSM_AUNZ..wsm_WorkOrderSchedule wws ON wws.BuildingID = wsmbldg.BuildingId
JOIN WSM_AUNZ..wsm_Ref_JobActivityAction wrj ON wrj.JobActivityActionID = wws.JobActivityActionID
JOIN WSM_AUNZ..wsm_contact wc ON wc.BuildingID = ttj.BuildingID
JOIN WSM_AUNZ..wsm_TSRSurveyAnswer TA ON TA.JobId = ttj.JobID --AND WSM_AUNZ.dbo.wsm_TSRSurveyAnswer.clientId = wsmbldg.CLIENTID
JOIN WSM_AUNZ..wsm_TSRSurvey TS ON TS.Q_Id = TA.Q_Id
JOIN LOCA l ON e.LOCAID = l.LOCAID
    AND l.LOCADESC LIKE 'DEX%'
    AND b.INACTIVE <> 'Y'
```

Comment: Please post execution plan https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Answer (score 0):

would be difficult for me to create similar structure in my db but few suggestions s below.

- Write 'With (Nolock)' in all table name end (add in join as well)
- Keep practice of writing Key word like Inner join, Left Join,
- Need to check indexing
- Run stats of all your table every morning (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187348.aspx)
- Proper Index require.
- Add condition in Where clause instead of joins like 'AND l.LOCADESC like 'DEX%' AND b.INACTIVE <> 'Y''
  Let me know further  how much improvement done so we may look further.

Comment: (1)Do not put NOLOCK everywhere it can give you Dirty data.
(2) practice writting INNER JOIN ,LEFT JOIN it does't give you performance benefits
(3) UPdate statistics every morning REALLY under what workload?
your answer is not qualifying as Answer

Comment: - 'With (No Lock)' gave good performance In case if data insertion is not in continuously.

Answer (score -1):

1) First remove distinct clause and put all the columns in group by so it could return you only distinct values through group by.
2)Check for any missing indexes
3) share explain paln.